# SignalR and MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, signalr

I am  trying to get the sample https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/QuickStart-Hubs to run with MVC4.

I added

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and have inlcuded jquery before singlar javascriptfiles in my html.
But i am getting the Chrome console error

```
http://localhost:35787/signalr/hubs/ 403 (Forbidden) 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
```

Of course i installed the nuget-package and created the hub class. I have no folder /signalr/hubs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created a folder "/signalr/hubs" in my project where i saved my hubs. This caused the error! After i removed it it works.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'll remove my comment. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Did you just move the Hub-classes to root or what?

Comment: it doesn't matter if they are in root or not. don't use a /signalr/hubs directory in your project

Answer (score 2):

Register the Hub on top before the WebAPI route.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

If the above method does not work then try this

```
<system.webServer> <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> </modules>
```

for more info read:
https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq

Answer (score 0):

Is the route registered?

Application_Start:

```
...
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
...
```

Also mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq)